# Using angular7 how to get dataBase updated value after component call using server API

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6, angular2-routing, angular7

After login success, I am getting data in database showing dashboard, but the scenario is I have to get updated data from the database without component reload

Comment: Do a `get` request that takes the updated value from the database, then `subscribe` to it and update your data with the data recieved from the db. Also, this question is going to be downvoted, so please attach some usefull code, thank you.

Comment: Already its working get request, but scenario is if someone update database, instantly I have to get data updated

Comment: You need to use mechanism of web socket for example you can use Socket.io.

Comment: That's not *natively* possible. You should implement some kind of websocket that keep listening for changes. Or, the worst way possible, add a setTimeout of 5 seconds that check the data and update your client data if needed.

Comment: ok than you so much

Answer (score 0):

this.pollingData = Observable.interval(5000).switchMap(() => http.post('ur URL/GetMethod')).map((data) => data.json()).subscribe((data) => { this.data = data });

Comment: Hello to all, i got the solution for get updated value from database for this you have to install rxjs-compat or you can manually add your component rxjs. and alos unsubscrube this subsciption other wise it will be run on when your component close